# Git: How to modify a commit shared with multiple branches

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following tree:

```
branch1               G---H---I
                     /   
master       A---B---C---D---E---F
                          \
branch2                    M---N---O
```

I need to make some modifications in B. Is there any easy way to spread the modifications to all the branches (master, branch1 and branch2) ?

Comment: Why do you want to change history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way to do this is:

1. Create a new branch from B

   `git checkout -b BPRIME SHA_OF_B`
2. Make some changes, and commit them. you're graph will look like:

   ```
   BPRIME              B'
                      /  
   branch1           /   G---H---I
                    /   /   
   master       A---B---C---D---E---F
                             \
   branch2                    M---N---O
   ```
3. Then cherry pick the commits from BPRIME to each of the branches.

   ```
   $ git checkout branch1 && git cherry-pick B'
   $ git checkout master && git cherry-pick B'
   $ git checkout branch2 && git cherry-pick B'
   ```

This is the safest option because you are *not* changing the history.

Answer (score 0):

Make the new commit in master branch and then rebase the other branches with the master.

Comment: I need to continue working with the branches separately. So, if I understood you correctly, this is not what I need.

Comment: You can still continue working separately in all your branches after rebasing with the master

Comment: You are right, but I would like to keep history as it is.